# Ng-Repeat - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my ng-repeat

```
<div ng-if="feed.link" articlesource source='{{article.link}}' class="post" ng-    repeat="article in data.value.items | limitTo:5"> 

            <img ng-if="articlesource != 'FACEBOOK'" title="{{article.title}}" alt="{{article.title}}" class="blog-image-ind" src="{{article.image}}" height="100" width="240" style="float:left;"> 
            <img ng-if="articlesource == 'FACEBOOK'" title="{{article.title}}" alt="{{article.title}}" class="blog-image-ind" src="/shared/images/facebook_long.png" height="100" width="240" style="float:left;"> 
            <div class="postMid"> 
                <H3><a style="color: #A4A4A4;" href="{{article.link}}">{{article.title | htmlToPlaintext | ellipsis:40}}</a></H3>
                <div> {{article.description | htmlToPlaintext | blogellipsis:160}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="postRight"> 
                <p> {{article.pubDate.substr(0, article.pubDate.indexOf(':')-2).trim()}}
                <br>
                <div ng-if="feed.name != 'THE FEED'"><p ng-if="articlesource != 'FACEBOOK' || feed.name != 'THE FEED'">BY {{article['dc:creator'] | uppercase}}</p></div>
                <p ng-if="feed.name == 'THE FEED'">{{articlesource}}</p>
                </p>

                <a ng-if="articlesource != 'FACEBOOK'" class="postRight" href="https://sam.containerandpackaging.com">{{article['slash:comments']}} Comments </a>   

            </div>
            <br clear="all"> 
        </div>
```

I would like to add something into my ng-repeat that would allow a border on all of the bottom of the divs except for the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Css

```
div.post {
  border-bottom: #ff0000;
}

div.post:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

The :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on the repeater with the condition that `$last` isnt true:

```
ng-class="{'myBorderClass : !$last }"
```

`$last` is `true` on the last iteration of your repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can use ng-repeat's $last value to set up ng-class. Something like pseudo code below.

```
<div ng-class="{'noborderclass':$last}"></div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. You need `!last` since the uesr wants everything to get a border, **except** the last one

Comment: @Kousha That's why the class name is "noborderclass"…

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: Javascript (Angular), or CSS. With angular, you can use `$last` like so:

```
<div ng-class="{'with-border': !$last}">
```

With CSS, you can use the selector `:last-of-type`:

```
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Personally, I go with CSS, cause I trust CSS more than JS.